# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.platformThreadFactory() while running fabric-sdk-java in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic12c, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using [**fabric-sdk-java client**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) to interact with my **Hyperledger Fabric V1.0 network** setup locally. Everything is working fine when running the client as standalone java application. But when I am using the same within the **application.ear** which is deployed in **Weblogic 12c** server, I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.platformThreadFactory()Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory;
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil.getThreadFactory(GrpcUtil.java:482)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$1.create(GrpcUtil.java:421)
    at io.grpc.internal.GrpcUtil$1.create(GrpcUtil.java:417)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder.getInternal(SharedResourceHolder.java:104)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourceHolder.get(SharedResourceHolder.java:74)
    at io.grpc.internal.SharedResourcePool.getObject(SharedResourcePool.java:35)
    at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.<init>(ManagedChannelImpl.java:383)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build(AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:331)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.OrdererClient.sendDeliver(OrdererClient.java:220)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Orderer.sendDeliver(Orderer.java:172)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.seekBlock(Channel.java:1198)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLatestBlock(Channel.java:1274)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getLastConfigIndex(Channel.java:1097)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.getConfigurationBlock(Channel.java:1028)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.parseConfigBlock(Channel.java:949)
    at org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel.initialize(Channel.java:676)
    ......
```

Since all of these dependencies are inside [**fabric-sdk-java**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) I am not sure where to do its fix. I had seen some post telling it is the issue with [guava version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0). [**fabric-sdk-java**](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) having the dependency with **guava version 19**.

I don't understand why it is working while running as standalone java application, but this issues coming after deploying in **Weblogic 12c** server.

Do I need to add anything more to work this in **Weblogic 12c** server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of such exceptions are caused by mismatched versions. For example, the method was not present in previous version, but was added in the latter, and you are using the previous version. So the class is there (it's not a ClassNotFoundException), but it does not have a method with this specific signature the calling code expects.

You should carefully examine your classpath. Locate the jar which contains the `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors` class. Check that you don't have two by some mistake. And try to find an official combination of jars that are known to work together.

And of course, welcome to classpath hell!